# Hostapd and lighttpd - manually download?

Tags: kali-linux, hostapd, lighttpd

Is there any alternative to command `apt-get install *name of package*`

When I type the same command `apt-get install *name of package*` from which website that packages are downloaded? Is it possible to visit that site and download the zip folder?

If I download hostapd and lighttpd using web browser how I can install them.
Which websites should I use to download (there are many out there)?

Comment: Note that Kali is a distribution for advanced users and mostly intended to run in virtual machines without installing, for penetration testing activities. If you want a distribution for everyday life, use Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of sites from which packages are loaded by inspecting [`/etc/apt/sources.list`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/apt/sources.list.5.en.html) as well as files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

You can download a package file with `apt-get download`, if you want to look inside for some reason. The package files that you installed are kept in `/var/cache/apt/archives` until the cache gets purged. The packages are in [deb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_(file_format)) format, not zip. You can use `dpkg-deb` or an archive viewer to look inside. If you just want to print the URL and not download the file, you can use `apt-get download --print-uris`.

There is rarely any reason to install software without using the package manager, except for software that isn't available as a package. For example, both hostapd and lighttpd are available as packages, so the way to install them is with `apt-get install` (or equivalent: `apt install`, `aptitude install`, a GUI package manager, …), not with a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a package can be as simple as a Google search.
Also, you can try to find the packages you need in the [Kali repository](https://pkg.kali.org/) or the [Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org).

After you have downloaded the packages install them from a terminal with `dpkg -i package.deb` or from the from Software Center if Kali has one (double-click on the .deb file, but I am not sure if Kali has a Software Center like Ubuntu has).

Comment: Excuse me for inconvenience, I knew that site works on voting system, and I tried to click on "upvote" button but it didn't register the vote because  I had less than 15 points, in addition to that please accept my apology that I didn't notice the "accept answer" button, I'm a new user on StackExchange and I totally overlook the "accept answer" button on this and previous questions although I blame my monitor for strange contrast + the grey color of the button didn't help much. Sorry once again.

Comment: This is poor advice. The normal way to install a package is not to look for it on the web, download it and then install it with `dpkg`, but to tell `apt` the package name and let it download from the proper repository. Looking in random repositories is likely to produce mismatched versions and cause countless incompatibilities.

Comment: Well I answered the OP's question "Is it possible to visit that site and download the zip folder ?". He might not have internet connection, company policy might forbid access to external repositories or you might want to install different version than the one present in the repository.